# No Inserta en sqlite (Android Studio)

Tags: android, base-de-datos

Tengo esta sentencia para instertar en una sqlite, pero no inserta nada. La app no me da error cuando se ejecuta esta sentencia. He comprobado todos los valores que le paso al insert y son correctos, simplemente no inserta nada en la tabla de la base de dato. Por supuesto falta el campo ID que es autoincrement.

```
                fechaalta =  String.valueOf(editextdia.getText());
            horaalta =  String.valueOf(edithora.getText());
            Cero = 0;
            Boole = 'S';

            FSDbHelper dbencuentroescritura = new FSDbHelper(MainJornadas.this);
            SQLiteDatabase insertarencuentro = dbencuentroescritura.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues contentValuesencuentro = new ContentValues();
            contentValuesencuentro.put(InContract.JornadasColumnas.IDDIV, diviid);
            contentValuesencuentro.put(InContract.JornadasColumnas.IDNJOR, NumJornadas);
            contentValuesencuentro.put(InContract.JornadasColumnas.IDCAMPO, CodigoCampo);
            contentValuesencuentro.put(InContract.JornadasColumnas.FECHA, fechaalta);
            contentValuesencuentro.put(InContract.JornadasColumnas.HORA, horaalta);
            contentValuesencuentro.put(InContract.JornadasColumnas.EQUIPOl, CodigoEquipoLocal);
            contentValuesencuentro.put(InContract.JornadasColumnas.RESULTADOL, Cero);
            contentValuesencuentro.put(InContract.JornadasColumnas.EQUIPOV, CodigoEquipoVisitante);
            contentValuesencuentro.put(InContract.JornadasColumnas.RESULTADOV, Cero);
            contentValuesencuentro.put(InContract.JornadasColumnas.TERMINADO, Boole);
            contentValuesencuentro.put(InContract.JornadasColumnas.REVISADO, Boole);
            contentValuesencuentro.put(InContract.JornadasColumnas.ARBITRO, Boole);
            contentValuesencuentro.put(InContract.JornadasColumnas.INCOMTL, Boole);
            contentValuesencuentro.put(InContract.JornadasColumnas.INCOMTV, Boole);
            contentValuesencuentro.put(InContract.JornadasColumnas.INCOMPL, Boole);
            contentValuesencuentro.put(InContract.JornadasColumnas.INCOMPV, Boole);
            contentValuesencuentro.put(InContract.JornadasColumnas.IDARB, Cero);

            insertarencuentro.insert(InContract.JornadasColumnas.TABLA_JORNADAS, null, contentValuesencuentro);
            dbencuentroescritura.close();
            insertarencuentro.close();
```

Comment: este código es Java... C#.net...? qué paquete tienes para interactuar con SQLite?

Comment: Es raro que no inserte y no de error, has comprobado mediante un debug que llega hasta la sentencia que ejecuta el insert ? @IriaPoncelaBlanco es Java

Comment: Bien, primero que nada, ¿Podrías mostrar el LogCat? Segundo, ¿Podrías mostrar el botón con el cual ejecutas la acción del insert? Porque veo que estas pasando `EditText` pero no veo el código del `Botón`.